# Insert audio in tag description

Tags: javascript, kml

I'm new here and am having trouble with a kml. I'm trying to add audio into the tag  but still could not . I saw that webkit is used to render the html content then as it supports html5 tried to use the audio tag with one based on the w3schools example, type this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" >
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
      <name> CDATA example </name>
      <description>
        <[CDATA[
          <audio controls>
                <source src="dizzy.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element .
          </audio >
        ]]>
      </description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

appeared but the text between the tags of audio which means that html5 is not supported right? So I also tried as is done with the old html , like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8">
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
      <name> CDATA example </name>
      <description>
        <[CDATA[
          <embed height="50" width="100" src="dizzy.mp3">
        ]]>
      </description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates> 102.595626,14.996729 < / coordinates >
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml >
```

But didn't work.I tried use the object tag to embed a swf on the page. But when I open the balloon of point in google earth and the default message appears when you do not have flashplayer installed, but i already installed and nothing. Has anyone experienced this? Finally my question is, how insert an audio in ballon of a placemark to open the kml file in google earth desktop application?  Thanks for the attention.

Comment: How are you trying to display the KML? On a web page?  A Google Map?

Comment: I'm trying on google earth standalone application.